# How to remove my Gitlab.com account

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I'd like to remove my gitlab account but keep all of my projects associated with the second gitlab account.

I have many projects under several groups and subgroups, my first account created some of these, the rest I created with my second account.

**I can't:**

- Delete my account, it says I still am connected with 2 subgroups, which is true
- I can't remove myself from these subgroups, for some reason there's no button to leave a subgroup
- If I remove myself from the parent group of these subgroups ( there is a button for that ), basically nothing happens cause I'm still associated with the subgroups

**What I already tried**

- Submitted a issue to Gitlab.com a while ago, without success https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/43420

Now I really want to get rid of it, since I'm not using it. Anyone encountered same issue and how did you solve it?

Comment: Can't you just change the email address and forget about it?

Comment: Are you the owner of those subgroups? If yes consider transferring the ownership and you should be able to do that. Also, could you please share the issue link here.

Comment: I am the owner, but there's no way I can transfer ownership of a subgroup anywhere ( I'm on gitlab.com, not my personal gitlab-ce ).
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/43420

Comment: Great. Further discussion here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/45513

Answer (score 0):

Check if GitLab 11.10 (Jan. 2019) will help, with [issue 38564](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/38564) and [MR 26718](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/merge_requests/26718)

> ### Change the way it is checked if the user is last group owner
>
> We used to check the subgroup owners only among subgroup members, ignoring owners of the parent group.
> It changes that, so users can remove owners if they leave the organization.

That should help remove your account from the subgroup, and, ultimately, to remove your account.